# Materials not applying to object

Tags: materials, objects

I have some objects but for some reason when I modify the nodes in the materials it won't show any changes on the object.

The objects were imported from another project. Then joined to apply a simulation. Then separated. Now the materials aren't responding properly.

Am I missing something I should do?

https://we.tl/t-OZjP3VUWPE

[image]

Comment: Select the object and in the Material panel, check if the good material is applied to its faces?

Comment: if you really wanna know (!) the reason, provide your blend file. Else we can just guess.

Comment: Right! Sorry, here's the file https://we.tl/t-OZjP3VUWPE

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Answer (score -1):

I checked the blend file and it seems that the U isn't using the Glass U material at all, it's using the Iridescent.N material. If you change the values on that material then something will happen

Comment: How did you find that? Sorry but I can't find where it says it's using the Iridescent material. Thanks!!

Comment: When I removed the Iridescent material from the object, all the faces became the default  material, and when I adjusted the nodes of the material it showed changes